# Scroll when I move to a new backbone page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, scroll, backbone-views

I'm having trouble with my Backbone app. On my home page, I have a form. When users submit, they're taken to a results page. The home page doesn't scroll, but the results page should. It does when I refresh, but it doesn't after I submit.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: When the user submits the form, how are you navigating them to the new page?

Comment: There's not enough description of the problem to provide any help. Please provide more detail as to the nature of the problem, being specific about what you've done, what the expected behavior is, and what, exactly, is happening.

Comment: The router redirects them to a new page. My router is here: https://github.com/sfahlberg/weatherornot/blob/master/js/router.js